# How to remove repeated HTML elements?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have the following [input.html](https://jsfiddle.net/23Lb5q4k/)  that has several repeated `<p>..</p>` elements. For example, `<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>` is repeated 3 times.

**input.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p>France</p>
<p>2178</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>888</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>921</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>1618.5</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>1321</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>1513</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>France</p>
<p>1899</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>2665.5</p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>345</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and I would like to remove the repeated `<p>..</p>` elements, leaving only the first ocurrence of each element.

**out.html**

```html
<html>
<body>

<p><strong><span style='font-size:24px;color:blue;'>Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:20px;color:green;'>Car</span></strong></p>
<p>France</p>
<p>2178</p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>888</p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:20px;color:red;'>Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>921</p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:18px;color:#F87217;'>Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:20px;color:green;'>Car</span></strong></p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>1618.5</p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>1321</p>
<p>1513</p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:20px;color:red;'>Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>France</p>
<p>1899</p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:18px;color:#C48189;'>Enterprise</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style='font-size:20px;color:red;'>Mon</span></strong></p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>2665.5</p>
<p>345</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to add the `<p>` elements within an array and then invoking `uniq` but it doesn't work, because the length of array `a` is the same as length of array `b`

How can I do this?

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = File.open("input.html") { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }

a=[]
doc.css("p").each{|el| a.push(el) }

b = a.uniq
```

Comment: When asking, it's important to reduce your input code, data and resulting output to the most minimal necessary to still demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that adds confusion. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: You can't use `uniq`, not because the array length is the same, but because each element is unique. Nodes have unique identifiers as do any subnodes.

Comment: "remove the repeated <p>..</p> elements, leaving only the first ocurrence of each element." Why are there so many repeated lines in your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

This could led you on the right direction, it is not clear on your example if you want to remove the second Car for example, but the question is to remove duplicated p's

```
require 'nokogiri' 

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
<body>
  <p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
  <p>France</p>
  <p>2178</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
  <p><strong><span style="background-color:yellow; font-size: 16px;">Germany</span></strong></p>
  <p>888</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
  <p><strong><span style="background-color:yellow; font-size: 16px;">Germany</span></strong></p>
  <p>921</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
  <p>Canada</p>
  <p>1618.5</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
  <p><strong><span style="background-color:yellow; font-size: 16px;">Germany</span></strong></p>
  <p>1321</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
  <p><strong><span style="background-color:yellow; font-size: 16px;">Germany</span></strong></p>
  <p>1513</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
  <p>France</p>
  <p>1899</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
  <p>Canada</p>
  <p>2665.5</p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
  <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
  <p>Canada</p>
  <p>345</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT
printed = []
doc.xpath('//p', '//strong//span').each do |text|
  content = text.content.gsub(/\s/, '')
  if !content.empty? && !printed.include?(content)
    printed.push(content)
    p content
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually for the case of `Car`, it appears more than once below the "main" `<p>` that has font size 24px. Then I'd like to leave only first `Car` below `Midmarket`. Leave first `Car` below `Government` and so on. The same for the countries. Additionally, is there a way to have the output in HTML format and not only test values?

Comment: yes, you can, instead of printing `content`, you can print `text.to_s`

Comment: Thanks. It prints as HTML following your suggestion. Now the output looks similar but still not what I'm looking for. The "main" paragraphs would be those with font size=24px. Maybe, I didn't explain good enough before, but I like to remove the repeated values that appear after those paragraphs with size 24.  Below Midmarket there are 3 Car, below Government 3 Car. So, only leave one Car below each of them. The same for the other values. I hope make sense

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML needed to be reduced; there are no reasons to have more than one duplicate to test code that creates unique values.

Also, to make it more obvious what's being removed I massaged the HTML, sorting the nodes to group the duplicates.

I'd start with this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'set'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<body>
<html>
<p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
<p>888</p>
<p>921</p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>Canada</p>
<p>France</p>
<p>France</p>
<p>Germany</p>
<p>Germany</p>
</body>
</html>
EOT
```

Before running the HTML contains:

```
doc.search('p').size # => 21
```

Here's how to remove the duplicates:

```
p_nodes = Set.new

doc.search('p').each { |p|  
  if p_nodes.include?(p.to_html)
    p.remove
  else
    p_nodes.add(p.to_html)
  end
}
```

After running the code the HTML contains:

```
doc.search('p').size # => 12
```

Which results in:

```
puts doc.to_html

# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> 
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:#C48189; font-size: 24px;">Enterprise</span></strong></p>
# >> 
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:#F87217; font-size: 24px;">Government</span></strong></p>
# >> 
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:blue; font-size: 24px;">Midmarket</span></strong></p>
# >> 
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p>
# >> </p>
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
# >> <p>888</p>
# >> <p>921</p>
# >> <p>Canada</p>
# >> 
# >> <p>France</p>
# >> 
# >> <p>Germany</p>
# >> 
# >> 
# >> </body></html>
```

[Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is performing the magic. A Set is similar to a [Hash](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html) only each element doesn't have a value associated with it, it's only the key. And, like a Hash, a Set can only contain one instance of that element, which, in this case, is the text version of that particular `<p>` node. The resulting behavior is that each node is checked against the `p_nodes` set to see if it already exists, and is removed if it does, otherwise it's added until every `<p>` node has been checked.

---

*Note*: Nokogiri isn't removing the Text nodes containing the line-ends that trail the `<p>` nodes, which is why there are gaps. Browsers "gobble blanks" so the resulting rendered HTML should look the same, only without the duplicates.

After running, the output shows:

```
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p>
# >> </p>
```

I think this is the result of Nokogiri seeing that the HTML is malformed. There are three lines that don't have proper closing `</p>` tags

```
<p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong><p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
<p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong><p>
```

and in the process of silently fixing the HTML a spurious pair are added. This happens because the people generating HTML don't pay attention to the details.

These particular nodes are the cause of the above empty `<p>` node and the duplicated "Cars" lines above.

Normally, Nokogiri will flag markup errors if they're significant using the [`Nokogiri::XML::Document#errors`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Document.html#errors-instance_method) method but `<p>` have optional closing tags, so this might be leaking through a crack.

Fixing the lines that are malformed results in no "Cars" duplicates or the empty `<p>` node, from:

```
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> <p>
# >> </p>
```

to:

```
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:green; font-size: 20px;">Car</span></strong></p>
# >> 
# >> <p><strong><span style="color:red; font-size: 20px;">Mon</span></strong></p>
# >>
```

Sometimes we have to preprocess documents to fix them prior to passing them to Nokogiri if the markup is too badly malformed. Nokogiri can only do so much.

Here's what happens after a parser does fixups; This is correct markup:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p>foo</p>
EOT

doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body>\n" +
#    "<p>foo</p>\n" +
#    "</body></html>\n"
```

which Nokogiri does no fixup, versus:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p>foo<p>
EOT

doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body>\n" +
#    "<p>foo</p>\n" +
#    "<p>\n" +
#    "</p>\n" +
#    "</body></html>\n"
```

Notice how Nokogiri had to close the first and second `<p>` tags, resulting in an extraneous `<p></p>` pair, not in the original document. This *will* be reflected in the rendered output of a page, because the browser will display it as an paragraph break, but it's up to you to write code to manage that, as said above. From the point that Nokogiri inserted the closing `</p>` to the end of the document it's likely that the display will be different from what was expected, hence the need to preprocess and fix the incoming HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your approach and solution shared. I get the point about to reduce the input sample. Said that, I tested your code with the input.html I show in post and the output is similar but different to the output I'm trying to get.   Not sure if you tried with my sample input.

Comment: The problem is your input is malformed as I showed above. That can affect the output of any XML/HTML parser. Fix the input so it's correct first then it's possible to find a stable output. The method of reducing the output is very standard, but because the parser must try to make sense of the input, the DOM it presents and that is searched, can be different than what we, as programmers, expect. I'll try to add an example to show what can happen.

Comment: I´ve just modified the input sample on original post, validated with `https://validator.w3.org/` and getting any error.

Comment: Sigh. Then you're changing your question. And, unfortunately, your input is still malformed. Multiple occurrences of `<p>...<p>` still exist.

Comment: I haven't changed the input, only added <head> and <title> elements as suggested by `https://validator.w3.org`. And haven´t changed the output in original post. So, is still the same question. I don´t understand why is malformed and the validator reports no errors.

Comment: There are unterminated `<p>` tags in your input. The closing `</p>` is optional per the specification that browsers follow, but a parser, like Nokogiri, wants everything to make sense because they're XML-based so it fixes the markup to be syntactically correct _as it thinks the DOM should be_. That's an important distinction. In your input you have multiple lines that do _not_ have terminating `</p>`. Nokogiri will attempt to fix those, but the resulting DOM isn't quite right, and, as a result, there are spurious results. Look at the "Car" and "Monday" lines in your input; `</p>` are missing.

Comment: Get it! thank you. I've fixed the lines with missing `</p>` tags. I run your code again and the output is similar to my expected output, but not equal and the main difference appears below `Government` part.

Comment: In the question you say: "remove the repeated <p>..</p> elements, leaving only the first ocurrence of each element." If so, why are there so many repeated lines in your desired output? Sort your desired output and look at the resulting lines. Your question isn't well asked and has remained so.